# Batch replacing .m4v with a different audio track

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, batch, mp3

I have a list of .m4v files. I have a list of .mp3 files (which happen to be the same file name as the *corresponding* .m4v files).

The .m4v files contain lower quality audio. The .mp3 files contain a better quality audio.

I would like to replace the audio in the .m4v files, with the *corresponding* audio in the .mp3 files.

I would not like to do this individually for 10000+ files, in either mkvmerge or ffmpeg.

I have tried a batch script with something like this but to no avail:

> FOR %%a IN ("*.m4v") DO ffmpeg -i "${%%a}" -i "${%%a//.m4v/.mp3}"
>   -vcodec copy -acodec copy "${%%a//.m4v/.mp4}"
>
> pause

As well as (as I wanted the output in a different directory):

> FOR %%a IN ("*.m4v") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%a" -vcodec copy -acodec copy
>   "outputDirFoo123\%%~na.mp4"
>
> pause

These so far have been unsuccessful (have only encountered errors). I am not sure how to fix this.

Could someone please indicate how I can batch process what I want above? Is there a better way to do it than I am here?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
FOR %%a IN ("*.m4v") DO ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%%~na.mp3" -map 0:v -map 1:a -c copy "newpath\%%~na.mp4"

pause
```

Comment: Thank you! I received another error that I had encountered previously, but then I realised I had not created the output directory (I thought ffmpeg would automatically create the directory structure if not found)! Appreciate your help.